# UI: Which one is better Menu hierarchy for better Usability

Tags: user-interface, web-applications, usability

I have 3 objects, each one is an instance of 3 other classes which inherits or extends the same super class. All 3 objects have same functions() like say ViewA, ViewB, ViewC, ViewD.

My question is **How to arrange the Menu hierarchy in UI for better Usability**. Should it be like in image given below, where each function is a submenu of the main object menu.
[image: Heirarchy Option 1]

**Or**

Should I use Menu as shown in below image where each function is a main menu. For Example when user opens ViewA he can Filter the displayed items according to Obj1, Obj2, Obj3 or Obj1 and obj2 combined. In below menu Obj1Menu, Obj2menu,Obj3Menu are used just to manage objects.

[image: Hierarchy option 2]

Let me know if you didn't understand my question.

Comment: Please describe the real world model, because this is too abstract to give a usability advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, the objects have the same interface. In this case i would extract the "functions" in a separate menu like:

```
Obj1  Obj2   Obj3 ...
```

other menu (active in each object)

```
viewA
viewB
viewC
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons along one line don't explain the object model, so it seems a bad decision.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the users which element (Object or View) they consider to be the top of the hierarchy and use that as the start point for the menu navigation.